# Improve lighting and walls

Tags: node-editor, lighting, photorealism

This is a render (with Cycles) of a building entrance hall.

First, I need a cement walls painted white. How can I do it using only nodes?

For lighting I'm using two point lights on the roof and one emission node inside the elevator. How can I improve de lighting of the scene to achieve photorealism?

[image]

Comment: [Same question was previously closed as "Primarily Opinion Based".](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200743/how-to-get-a-more-realistic-result)  Please don't simply delete and re-ask.  Any edit to the original question will have it considered for re-opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the cement you could overlap 2 (or more) levels of noise, one very thin for the cement texture, and one much bigger for some holes. Also maybe try a bit of glossiness with a *Layer Weight* as factor. Iit would give something like that:

[image]

It can also be more subtle:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for both examples, they are very useful!

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stack exchange! your scene is water tight (i.e close internally without holes)? There are 3 ways to add lighting to your scene:

1. with the lights objects that blender provides...
2. with mesh object lights (any object and become it emissive through the materials)...
3. with hdris, which are 360 deg images with color and with lighting information, that works to simply and with ease light your scene with the colors from the surrounding, you will get more realistic reflections of the background scene and softer/hard reflections, except for the mesh lights and lights that you can color them with any color, get reflections from this objects itself, but not get the same result as the hdri image...

there are some cons and pros of using them, you should use the mesh lights mostly for objects like light bulb, lamps, or any object you want to have light or produce light. For adding plane lights for example you can use either one or another for interior lighting.

For background lighting you should use an hdri, and depending in how is your scene and models structure it can subtly or a lot affect the lighting of your interior, depending if there any holes such as windows (with or without glass on them,curtains or any translucent or transparent object) that lets the light scatter through...

So for your lighting in this scene what is the image reference of the real scene (i guess you made this starting with a reference) you want to achieve and the type of lighting (cool,warm,neutral)? matching the lighting of a real life reference can be tricky sometimes...

Additionally for increase more realism your scene, this current one is too clean the materials, you need to work more in the materials as well, with adding some subtle or a lot of effects like damage,dirt,grunge some bump or normal maps, sometimes displacement depending the type of object to detail, all this done to the materials using pbr textures preferably which you can download online...

But you can use procedural materials, but this is the hardest sometimes and the advanced way, and if you want to make them from scratch will be a waste of time, but at least you can use it in any scene and objects, but since is procedural (it doesn't make magic for different characterization of the textures and accurate detailing sometimes, but you can in manual texturing, or use both is good), sometimes you might need some manual texturing, or using image textures with procedural materials, and like this you can apply them into areas like the floor, walls, ceiling firstly, also other objects surround like metals,wood, glass,plastic, etc...

You can try the node setup from below answer to get some effects on the walls, that's one the easiest node setups to make for this type of subtle details, but also if you care about closeups renders, you might need to add more detail size on your materials/textures for that purpose...

Comment: Thank you very much for all the advices!